# Encoding HMAC256 - Java to Python

Tags: python, encoding

I need to convert the below Java code into Python but seem to run into issues retrieving the required output. I was hoping to see if anyone could pinpoint my error

Java code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const qs = require('query-string')

const accessKey = '0a16ca22a837af8acae3b70f1952f311'
const accessSecret = 'fe266ab860ef6734192a9e90ad39405b'

const method = 'GET' 
const timestamp = 1629339206369
const path = '/api/v2/loan/config'     
const signStr = `method=${method}&path=${path}&timestamp=${timestamp}`
// "method=GET&path=/api/v2/loan/config&timestamp=1629339206369"

const sign = crypto.createHmac('sha256', accessSecret).update(signStr).digest('hex');
```

Java output:

```
8dafe94777e9130869ceedf9f123c5f6552efcff3cb139591834eb8a82cc7504
```

Python code:

```
signStr =  "method=GET&path=/api/v2/loan/config&timestamp=1629339206369"
accessSecret  = 'fe266ab860ef6734192a9e90ad39405b'
resp = hmac.new(accessSecret.encode('utf-8'), signStr.encode('utf-8'), 
hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Python output:

```
    f751679a9640cdea16a2cb625a2e797c7190cfd6901e729dcd6ca66519907ac6
```

Thanks

Comment: When I gave your input to https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html, it said that Python was giving the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code on node.js, and got the exact same answer as Python.

```
> const method = 'GET' 
> const timestamp = 1629339206369
> const path = '/api/v2/loan/config'     
> const signStr = `method=${method}&path=${path}&timestamp=${timestamp}`
> signStr
'method=GET&path=/api/v2/loan/config&timestamp=1629339206369'
> const sign = crypto.createHmac('sha256', accessSecret).update(signStr).digest('hex');
> sign
'f751679a9640cdea16a2cb625a2e797c7190cfd6901e729dcd6ca66519907ac6'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I got it from API doc and just took it as gospel